# Implement random array in a loop to get the sum

Tags: c, arrays

We are doing this right now at school, but I can't manage to get it right and I don't know what to try so I'm asking you guys. Probably there is a very easy solution to this and I know what I have to do in theory but I can get it done correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 10

double numbers[LEN];

void init()
{
int i;
for(i = 0; i < LEN; ++i)
{
    numbers[i] = (double)rand()/(double)rand();
}
}

void print()
{
int i;
for(i = 0; i < LEN; ++i)
{
    printf("%d -> %lf\t", i, numbers[i]);
}
puts("");
}

double min()
{
double min = numbers[0];
int i;

for(i = 1; i < LEN; ++i)
{
    if(numbers[i]< min)
    {
        min = numbers[i];
    }
}

return min;
}

double max()
{
double max = numbers[0];
int i;

for(i = 1; i < LEN; ++i)
{
    if(numbers[i] > max)
    {
        max = numbers[i];
    }
}

return max;
}


void sort()
{
double min;
double hlp;

int i, j;
}

double sum()
{
double sum = 0.0;
//put your code here
 return sum;
}

double mean()
{
double mean = 0.0;
//put your code here
return mean;
}

double median()
{
double median = 0.0;
sort();
//put your code here
return median;
}

//double ....

//void plot()

int main()
{

print();
init();
print();
printf("min -> %lf\n", min());
printf("max -> %lf\n", max());
sum();
printf("Sum: %lf", sum);


return 0;
}
```

I need to sum up the random array numbers and then get the average and the median out of this. Please help me to write this syntax.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you write the other functions (like `print` and `max`)? Do you understand how they work? Do you know how to calculate average or mean of a series of numbers?

Comment: Please properly indent your code. As it stands it is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to progress in your tab and incremente a sum variable at each iteration by the current element.
Then you'll be able to calculate the average.
Good luck

Comment: Indeed, he needs to learn, but he still have work in order to implement this.

Comment: Was it a real suggestion ? >< I didn't get it